# Find date inside each month

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

In my project, in the repository, this select finds the nearest date with a currency id that is less than or equal to the date whose range I set.

```
@Query(value = "select e. *from exchange_rates e where e.date <=:currentDate and e.local_currency_id = :localCurrencyId order by e.downloaddate desc limit 1", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<ExchangeRate> findAllByDateAndLocalCurrency_Id(Date currentDate, Long localCurrencyId);
```

How can I find a date in each month that is greater than or equal to the date I want to bind, but with the condition that this date must be the closest to the end of each month. That is, you need an ID whose date (exactly the date, not downloaddate) is closest to the end of the month.

Tried doing something like this, but it didn't work

```
    @Query(value = "select e.date, e.id, e.date, e.local_currency_id, e.rate, e.downloaddate" +
                " from exchange_rates e " +
                "join (select local_currency_id, max(date) as max_date " +
                "from exchange_rates group by local_currency_id, date_trunc('month', date)) as m_date on e.date = m_date.max_date " +
                "where e.date >=:currentDate and e.date < m_date.max_date and e.local_currency_id = :localCurrencyId " +
                " order by e.downloaddate desc limit 1", nativeQuery = true)
        Optional<ExchangeRate> findAllByDateAndLocalCurrency_Id1(Date currentDate, Long localCurrencyId);
```

Formatted query:

```
SELECT
    e.date,
    e.id,
    e.date,
    e.local_currency_id,
    e.rate,
    e.downloaddate
FROM
    exchange_rates e
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            local_currency_id,
            max(date) AS max_date
        FROM
            exchange_rates
        GROUP BY
            local_currency_id,
            date_trunc('month', date)) AS m_date ON e.date = m_date.max_date
WHERE
    e.date >= :currentDate
    AND e.date < m_date.max_date
    AND e.local_currency_id = :localCurrencyId
ORDER BY
    e.downloaddate DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I recently answered a similar question [..last day of the month data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73593147/how-to-retrieve-the-last-day-of-the-month-data/73593700#73593700). See if that solution would fit your purpose.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver Thanks for your reply. Maybe I didn't apply your advice correctly. But I get the figure at the end of the month, but a month earlier.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver value = "select e.date, e.id, e.date, e.local_currency_id, e.rate, e.downloaddate" +
            " from exchange_rates e " +
            "join (select local_currency_id, max(date) as max_date " +
            "from exchange_rates group by local_currency_id, date_trunc('month', date)) as m_date on e.date = m_date.max_date " +
            "where e.date >=:currentDate and e.date < m_date.max_date and e.local_currency_id = :localCurrencyId " +
            " order by e.downloaddate desc limit 1", nativeQuery = true

Comment: Add the query to your question and format to make it easier to follow.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver Added a new select to my question

Comment: Please update your question with  sample data, as [formatted text](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) or a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14). **Do not post images**. Also post the results you get from your query and the desired results of that data - again no images.

Comment: By the way… Both `Date` classes are legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: 1) Define '...but it didn't work'?  2) Sample input data and expected output would go a long way to helping solving this.  3) Pretty sure `...AND e.date < m_date.max_date` is not helping as you are eliminating all `e.dates` that would make this `...ON e.date = m_date.max_date` work.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver I have an amount that needs to be divided by a certain number (this number is rate). One (rate) has different dates, that is, for example, this is the dollar rate and in different numbers the figure of this rate is different, depending on the date. When I enter a certain range of dates, for example from 2022-01-01 to 2022-05-01, then certain amounts appear in my select. So these amounts must be divided by the course, but the course must correspond to this amount for a certain month, and the date of this course must be the latest for this month.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve the last day of the month data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73593147/how-to-retrieve-the-last-day-of-the-month-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it worked for me:

```
    @Query(value = "select e.date, e.id, e.date, e.local_currency_id, e.rate, e.downloaddate" +
                    " from exchange_rates e " +
                    "join (select local_currency_id, max(date) as max_date " +
                    "from exchange_rates group by local_currency_id, date_trunc('month', date)) as m_date on e.date = m_date.max_date " +
                    "where e.date >=:currentDate and e.local_currency_id = :localCurrencyId " +
                    " order by date_trunc('month', e.downloaddate) desc limit 1", nativeQuery = true)
            Optional<ExchangeRate> findAllByDateAndLocalCurrency_Id1(Date currentDate, Long localCurrencyId);
```